# error in gamma link specification for lmer

Tags: r, lme4, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to fit a mixed-effects model with a gamma distribution. The most basic model has one fixed predictor and 1 random effect. No matter which link I specify (I've tried log, identity and inverse), I obtain the following error. My real data has zeros in Y, but even when I apply simulated data with only positive Y as below, it throws the same error.

```
mockdf = data.frame(y =  rnorm(100,77,6.5), x1 = sample(letters,100,replace = T), x2 = seq(1900,1999,1))
mod = lmer(y ~ (1|x1) + x2, family = gamma(link = 'identity'), na.action = na.exclude, data = mockdf)

Error in gamma(link = "identity") : 
  supplied argument name 'link' does not match 'x'
```

I searched through SO and couldn't find another person who ran into this error. Is my syntax incorrect?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hum, lmer function from lme4 doesn't support a `family` argument...

Comment: using `glmer`, as Roman mentioned... the family is `Gamma` (big G)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the quick response. Is there any way to incorporate random effects in a gamma-distributed model?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't sees @user20650 response until just now. Will attempt with edits.